# Qt app crashes on every message box

Tags: c++, macos, qt, osx-mavericks

Since upgrading on Maverick I have a strange issue on my Qt apps
They all crash when closing a simple Qmessagebox or event when doing alert() or confirm() inside javascript on a QWebView..

So if even javascript makes the app crash, I assume this is not wrong c++ code ?

I don't know where to start, what to try.
I've compiled with the prebuilt Qt 5.2.0 and one I compiled myself with the same result...

This is the crash log on Mac OSX:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   QtWidgets                       0x0000000100e963a1 QWidget::mapFromGlobal(QPoint const&) const + 49
1   QtWidgets                       0x0000000100e9ae56 QWidgetWindow::handleTabletEvent(QTabletEvent*) + 598
2   QtWidgets                       0x0000000100e9878d QWidgetWindow::event(QEvent*) + 509
3   QtWidgets                       0x0000000100e433bc QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 300
4   QtWidgets                       0x0000000100e45ef0 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 6224
5   QtCore                          0x00000001008dbbc2 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) + 114
6   QtGui                           0x000000010025e0df QGuiApplicationPrivate::processTabletEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::TabletEvent*) + 911
7   QtGui                           0x0000000100259fd0 QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent*) + 944
8   QtGui                           0x0000000100249a68 QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 56
9   libqcocoa.dylib                 0x0000000108b59a17 QCocoaEventDispatcherPrivate::processPostedEvents() + 295
10  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x0000000108b5a4f8 QCocoaEventDispatcherPrivate::postedEventsSourceCallback(void*) + 40
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff960c58f1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff960b7062 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff960b67ef __CFRunLoopRun + 831
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff960b6275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff89e53f0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff89e53b85 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 173
17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff89e53abc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff944f728e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff944f68db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff944ea9cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
21  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x0000000108b592a7 QCocoaEventDispatcher::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 2391
22  QtCore                          0x00000001008d905d QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 397
23  QtCore                          0x00000001008dc162 QCoreApplication::exec() + 354
24  @BUNDLEIDENTIFIER@              0x0000000100006d22 main + 130
25  @BUNDLEIDENTIFIER@              0x0000000100006c94 start + 52
```

The funny thing, I don't know if this is related but...
Qt Creatorr behaves the same way. When having a dialog (like preferences) and getting back to the main frame, it crashes.

Has this to do with some sort of 'back in focus' ?

Comment: Try restarting. I've been on mavericks since ~day 7 after release, and never had such a problem. This may be somehow a Qt bug specific to a particular architecture that OS X is installed  on - admittedly I only run 6 years old Core 2 hardware.

Comment: Do you have a simple test case? Then I'd report it in Qt's JIRA.

Comment: @KubaOber I tried couple of times (have 10.6 and 10.9 on different disks) on a macpro 2009 8core but without success

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld You mean some kind of compiled app example?

Comment: Vincent Duprez: Yes, a simple example that can be compiled and reproduces the problem for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, This is a known bug with Wacom attached Tablet input...

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-35984

No solution (yet)...