# Qt application quits unexpectedly on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, qt4

My Qt program runs well on Linux and Windows. However, when it's on Mac, for a specific button clicked, it may causes quit unexpected error. However, the weird part is, this error happens unpredictably. Sometimes it does happen but sometimes everything is fine. The slot function is just for showing another existed window and doing some normal computation. It works fine on another two OS. Below is the error information provided by mac. Could anyone tell me how to solve this please? Thanks a lot!

```
Process:         VigenereVis [2447]
Path:            /Users/USER/Desktop/*/VigenereVis.app/Contents/MacOS/VigenereVis
Identifier:      com.yourcompany.VigenereVis
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [165]
Responsible:     VigenereVis [2447]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-04-08 15:58:55.210 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  5906397F-7107-5863-B4B0-434214C07ECA

Sleep/Wake UUID: 1581FC20-6365-4366-9DB7-AAB3A8454BD5

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100096000 [  600K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Desktop/*/VigenereVis.app/Contents/MacOS/VigenereVis

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.yourcompany.VigenereVis     0x00000001000357c0 std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::operator[](unsigned long) + 16 (stl_vector.h:478)
1   com.yourcompany.VigenereVis     0x000000010002e81f Canvas::paint(QPainter*, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem const*, QWidget*) + 21519 (canvas.cpp:626)
2   QtGui                           0x00000001007876f0 QGraphicsScenePrivate::draw(QGraphicsItem*, QPainter*, QTransform const*, QTransform const*, QRegion*, QWidget*, double, QTransform const*, bool, bool) + 2496
3   QtGui                           0x0000000100787e12 QGraphicsScenePrivate::drawSubtreeRecursive(QGraphicsItem*, QPainter*, QTransform const*, QRegion*, QWidget*, double, QTransform const*) + 1234
4   QtGui                           0x00000001007888a3 QGraphicsScenePrivate::drawItems(QPainter*, QTransform const*, QRegion*, QWidget*) + 467
5   QtGui                           0x00000001007b00a3 QGraphicsView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) + 787
6   QtGui                           0x00000001001ea307 QWidget::event(QEvent*) + 2343
7   QtGui                           0x00000001005798ec QFrame::event(QEvent*) + 44
8   QtGui                           0x0000000100605bc7 QAbstractScrollArea::viewportEvent(QEvent*) + 23
9   QtGui                           0x00000001007b198b QGraphicsView::viewportEvent(QEvent*) + 123
10  QtGui                           0x0000000100607f50 QAbstractScrollAreaFilter::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*) + 48
11  QtCore                          0x0000000100f27cb7 QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendThroughObjectEventFilters(QObject*, QEvent*) + 151
12  QtGui                           0x000000010018d9be QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 142
13  QtGui                           0x0000000100194064 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 1060
14  QtCore                          0x0000000100f2820c QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) + 124
15  QtGui                           0x00000001001e073e QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) + 1822
16  QtGui                           0x00000001001e11b4 QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) + 1460
17  QtGui                           0x00000001001e04d0 QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) + 1200
18  QtGui                           0x00000001001e11b4 QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) + 1460
19  QtGui                           0x00000001001e1075 QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) + 1141
20  QtGui                           0x00000001001e1075 QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) + 1141
21  QtGui                           0x00000001001e1075 QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) + 1141
22  QtGui                           0x00000001001e1075 QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) + 1141
23  QtGui                           0x00000001001e1075 QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) + 1141
24  QtGui                           0x00000001001e1075 QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) + 1141
25  QtGui                           0x00000001001e1075 QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) + 1141
26  QtGui                           0x00000001001e1075 QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice*, QList<QObject*> const&, int, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) + 1141
27  QtGui                           0x00000001001e04d0 QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, int, QPainter*, QWidgetBackingStore*) + 1200
28  QtGui                           0x000000010013291a -[QCocoaView drawRect:] + 1786
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e76616f -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 3748
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e7649e4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1799
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e764dc0 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e762826 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 841
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e761fd1 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 314
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e75efbf -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2828
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e73e42a -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1680
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e757ff6 -[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 1972
37  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e7575a0 -[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 786
38  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e757220 -[NSWindow orderWindow:relativeTo:] + 162
39  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e7487d6 -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 51
40  QtGui                           0x00000001001293a3 QWidgetPrivate::show_sys() + 1123
41  QtGui                           0x00000001001e5448 QWidgetPrivate::show_helper() + 408
42  QtGui                           0x00000001001e6cff QWidget::setVisible(bool) + 511
43  com.yourcompany.VigenereVis     0x000000010000205b QWidget::show() + 27 (qwidget.h:494)
44  com.yourcompany.VigenereVis     0x0000000100015a8d VigenereVis::showAttackWindow() + 989 (vigenerevis.cpp:1920)
45  com.yourcompany.VigenereVis     0x0000000100067a5e VigenereVis::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) + 686 (moc_vigenerevis.cpp:153)
46  QtCore                          0x0000000100f401ee QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) + 1566
47  QtGui                           0x000000010080e321 QAbstractButton::clicked(bool) + 49
48  QtGui                           0x00000001005315c0 QAbstractButtonPrivate::emitClicked() + 64
49  QtGui                           0x00000001005327fa QAbstractButtonPrivate::click() + 154
50  QtGui                           0x0000000100532a51 QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) + 113
51  QtGui                           0x00000001001ea355 QWidget::event(QEvent*) + 2421
52  QtGui                           0x0000000100531848 QAbstractButton::event(QEvent*) + 40
53  QtGui                           0x00000001005cd595 QPushButton::event(QEvent*) + 69
54  QtGui                           0x000000010018d9ed QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 189
55  QtGui                           0x0000000100194590 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 2384
56  QtCore                          0x0000000100f2820c QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) + 124
57  QtGui                           0x0000000100191fdd QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(QWidget*, QMouseEvent*, QWidget*, QWidget*, QWidget**, QPointer<QWidget>&, bool) + 333
58  QtGui                           0x0000000100141acb qt_mac_handleMouseEvent(NSEvent*, QEvent::Type, Qt::MouseButton, QWidget*, bool) + 763
59  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e809235 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 781
60  QtGui                           0x0000000100136bb7 -[QCocoaWindow sendEvent:] + 87
61  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e7aa6e4 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2021
62  QtGui                           0x000000010013bbf4 -[QNSApplication sendEvent:] + 84
63  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e5fab89 -[NSApplication run] + 646
64  QtGui                           0x0000000100146a80 QEventDispatcherMac::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 1824
65  QtCore                          0x0000000100f27114 QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 68
66  QtCore                          0x0000000100f274c4 QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 324
67  QtCore                          0x0000000100f29bac QCoreApplication::exec() + 188
68  com.yourcompany.VigenereVis     0x0000000100001f35 main + 101 (main.cpp:10)
69  com.yourcompany.VigenereVis     0x0000000100001ea4 start + 52
```

Comment: I'm not a specialist in Mac, but this question is seems to be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735462/qt-app-crashes-on-every-message-box.

Comment: Something seems to be trying to access data in a std::vector out of range during the paint event. Do you have a custom paint function within your widget to be shown?